# How to group by two columns to show only one single row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

Below is my query which I am running against Postgres database.

```
SELECT ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
    ,md.col3
    ,ad.col4
    ,mcd.col5
    ,AVG(mcd.col5 / md.col3) AS dc
    ,AVG(md.col3 / ad.col4) AS cb
FROM tableCount AS md
INNER JOIN tablePop AS ad ON ad.col1 = md.col1
    AND ad.col2 = md.col2
INNER JOIN tableData AS mcd ON mcd.col1 = md.col1
    AND mcd.col2 = md.col2
WHERE md.col2 = 23
    AND md.col1 = '1'
GROUP BY ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
    ,md.col3
    ,ad.col4
    ,mcd.col5
ORDER BY md.col3 DESC limit 30
GROUP BY ad.col1
    ,ad.col2;
```

And below is the output I am getting back on the console with the use of above query-

```
col1    col2    col3        col4        col5        dc                                  cb
1       23      48108       224123      479         0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      89          0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      142         0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      1649        0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      14          0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      203         0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      52          0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      62          0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      65          0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
1       23      48108       224123      33          0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
```

- Now if you see my above output, `1` and `23` is coming multiple times in `col1` and `col2`. I would like to group them in one single row such that I would SUM `col3, col4, col5, dc and cb`.

So the output I would like to see it is -

```
col1    col2    col3        col4        col5        dc                                  cb
1       23      48108       2241230     278         0.00000000000000000000              0.00000000000000000000
```

Is this possible to do in SQL?

P.S Any Fiddle example would be great.

Comment: Why are you grouping by `md.col3, ad.col4, mcd.col5`, you could take the `max` of col3 and col4 and average of col5 and get what you need.

Comment: You are right, an SQLfiddle is always nice to work with. Go ahead and create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove `col5` from the `group by`:

```
SELECT ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
    ,md.col3
    ,ad.col4
    ,sum(mcd.col5) as col5
    ,AVG(mcd.col5 / md.col3) AS dc
    ,AVG(md.col3 / ad.col4) AS cb
FROM tableCount AS md
INNER JOIN tablePop AS ad ON ad.col1 = md.col1
    AND ad.col2 = md.col2
INNER JOIN tableData AS mcd ON mcd.col1 = md.col1
    AND mcd.col2 = md.col2
WHERE md.col2 = 23
    AND md.col1 = '1'
GROUP BY ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
    ,md.col3
    ,ad.col4
ORDER BY md.col3 DESC limit 30
```

I assume the last `group by` and `order by` are there accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

You can `SUM()` or take the `MAX()`, really it's only `col5` in your sample that is resulting in multiple rows, `GROUP BY` any non-aggregate field, and pick the appropriate aggregate for any other field:

```
SELECT ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
    ,MAX(md.col3)
    ,MAX(ad.col4)
    ,AVG(mcd.col5)
    ,AVG(mcd.col5 / md.col3) AS dc
    ,AVG(md.col3 / ad.col4) AS cb
FROM tableCount AS md
INNER JOIN tablePop AS ad ON ad.col1 = md.col1
    AND ad.col2 = md.col2
INNER JOIN tableData AS mcd ON mcd.col1 = md.col1
    AND mcd.col2 = md.col2
WHERE md.col2 = 23
    AND md.col1 = '1'
GROUP BY ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
ORDER BY md.col3 DESC limit 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
    ,min(md.col3)
    ,min(ad.col4)
    ,min(mcd.col5)
    ,AVG(mcd.col5 / md.col3) AS dc
    ,AVG(md.col3 / ad.col4) AS cb
FROM tableCount AS md
INNER JOIN tablePop AS ad ON ad.col1 = md.col1
    AND ad.col2 = md.col2
INNER JOIN tableData AS mcd ON mcd.col1 = md.col1
    AND mcd.col2 = md.col2
WHERE md.col2 = 23
    AND md.col1 = '1'
GROUP BY ad.col1
    ,ad.col2
ORDER BY min(md.col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your query to a derived table by making it a subquery with an alias.  Then you can select from it.

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, dc, sum(col3 + col4 + col5 + dc + cb) thesum
from (query from your question goes here) temp
group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, dc
```